# django STATIC_URL on production server

Tags: django, static

I want update same files from STATIC_URL.
But they did't update, because browser cache statics.

Can automatically make a **setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static-%s/' % <AUTO_INCREMENT>
```

and regular setting in nginx?

Or may have a component?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if these files are used for site design, i.e. they are css-files or images, you can use http://github.com/mintchaos/django_compressor or smth like this.
It generates new css file and sets for all included images special token (directly in css) every time some of css files is updated.